# RGBA format HEX into RGB format HEX? PHP

Tags: php, hex, rgb, rgba

I want to convert back and forth between RGBA-formated HEX colors (like`0xFF0000FF`) and RGB-formated HEX colors (like `0xFF0000`) in PHP.

How can I do this?

Comment: Should be as simple as stripping the last two chars from the RGBA string, and appending 'FF' to the RGB string.

Comment: How are the values you currently have stored?  As ints?  e.g. `$rgba = \xFF0000FF;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about these:

```
function rgbaToRgb ($rgba, $blend = 0xFFFFFF) {
    return (($rgba >> 8)*($rgba & 0xFF)/0xFF) * ($blend / 0xFFFFFF);
}

function rgbToRgba ($rgb) {
    return ($rgb << 8) | 0xFF;
}
```

$blend in the first is effectively a background color to blend with.

Edit: fix due to not enough space in ints ruining RGBA. 
RGBA is now handled as a four part array. RGB remains a number.:

```
function rgbaToRgb ($rgba, $blend = 0xFFFFFF) {
$rbg = array($rgba[0] * $rgba[3]/0xFF + ($blend>>16) * (0xFF-$rgba[3])/0xFF, $rgba[1] * $rgba[3]/0xFF + (($blend>>8)&0xFF)*(0xFF-$rgba[3])/0xFF, $rgba[2] * $rgba[3]/0xFF + ($blend&0xFF) * (0xFF-$rgba[3])/0xFF);
return ($rbg[0]<<16) + ($rbg[1]<<8) + $rbg[2];
}

function rgbToRgba ($rgb) {
    return array($rgb >> 16, ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF, $rgb & 0xFF, 0xFF);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

These two functions will do what you need:

```
function rgbaToRgb ($rgba) {
    return substr($rgba, 0, -2);
}

function rgbToRgba ($rgb) {
    return $rgb . "FF";
}
```

The first one simply removes the last two characters, whilst the second one simply appends `FF`.

Comment: As I said, I'm looking for other solution that using strings :)

Answer (score 0):

RGBA -> RGB should be simple, as it's just cutting off the last two digits. The other direction is impossible, as alpha information isn't encoded in RGB.

Comment: Well, reverse will be adding "FF" at the end. I'm looking for other solution that string -> cut last 2 characters -> hex

Answer (score 0):

As Frank mentioned, you can simply strip the last 2 digits.

The hex format is 3 pairs of numbers, the first pair Red value, the next is Green, and the next is blue. If you add another pair, it's assumed to be the alpha value.

Comment: I know both things, but I'm looking for bit-based solution.