# how to convert rgba to hex or rgb color code using php

Tags: php, rgba

Is it possible to convert rgba color code to hex or rgb equivalent color code in php. I have seared a lot but I found some js functions but not in php.

Please help

Comment: rgba and rgb are fundamentally incompatible, rgb can not contain the `a` alpha channel information. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6671570/1499781

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert RGBA color to RGB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049230/convert-rgba-color-to-rgb)

Comment: those all are written in js or in other format, is anybody knows how to convert rgba to hex in php.

Answer (score 0):

When there are sources in JavaScript it should not be a problem to migrate the code into PHP...

RGB to HEX (considering we have our R, G, B colors in `$r`, `$g`, `$b` variables):

```
function toHex($n) {
    $n = intval($n);
    if (!$n)
        return '00';

    $n = max(0, min($n, 255)); // make sure the $n is not bigger than 255 and not less than 0
    $index1 = (int) ($n - ($n % 16)) / 16;
    $index2 = (int) $n % 16;

    return substr("0123456789ABCDEF", $index1, 1) 
        . substr("0123456789ABCDEF", $index2, 1);
}

echo $hex = '#' . toHex($r) . toHex($g) . toHex($b);
```

Didn't tested but should be working. Should You need RGBa -> RGB conversion desirabily, let me know...